# xsd unique selector path: exclude specific elements

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, selector, unique

I have following xml and xsd as basic example for my question:

#### XML

```html
  <parentgroup>

    <parent id="1">
      <child id="2" />
      <child id="3" />
      <childgroup id="4">
        <child id="5" />
        <child id="2" />
      </childgroup>
      <child id="5" />
    </parent>


    <parent id="2">
      <childgroup id="33">
        <child id="1" />
        <child id="4" />
      </childgroup>
      <child id="1" />
      <child id="5" />
      <childgroup id="4">
        <child id="1" />
        <child id="6" />
      </childgroup>
    </parent>

  </parentgroup>
```

#### XSD

```html
<xsd:element name="parentgroup" type="parentgroup">
    <xsd:unique name="UniqueParentId">
      <xsd:selector xpath="child::parent"></xsd:selector>
      <xsd:field xpath="@id"></xsd:field>
    </xsd:unique>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:complexType name="parentgroup">
    <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xsd:element name="parent" type="parent" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">

        <xsd:unique name="UniqueChildId">
          <xsd:selector xpath=".//*"></xsd:selector>
          <xsd:field xpath="@id"></xsd:field>
        </xsd:unique>

      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:int" />
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="parent">
    <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
      <xsd:element name="child" type="child" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="childgroup" type="childgroup" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"></xsd:element>

    </xsd:choice>

    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:int" />
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="childgroup">
    <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xsd:element name="child" type="child" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"></xsd:element>

    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:int" />
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="child">
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:int" />
  </xsd:complexType>
```

#### Task

1. All parents have an unique "id" attr. and no child has the same "id" attr. like his parent.
2. Childs and Childgroups in a parent have unique "id" attr. excluding the Childs in the Childgroup. (ids are unique in the first depth plus parent)
3. Childs in a Childgroup have unique "id" attr. (so it is allowed that the ids of childs in a childgroup are equal to ids of childs out of the childgroup in the same parent, but its not allowed that it is euqal to id of own childgroup, like 2. point [(ids are unique in the first depth plus parent)] )

#### 1. Question

The points 1. and 2. are clear, but I dont know how to exclude the descendant of childgroup, i tried following but get always xpath syntax error

First Try

```html
     <xsd:element name="parent" type="parent" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">

        <xsd:unique name="UniqueChildId">
          <xsd:selector xpath=".//*[not(childgroup)]"></xsd:selector>
          <xsd:field xpath="@id"></xsd:field>
        </xsd:unique>

      </xsd:element>
```

Second Try

```html
     <xsd:element name="parent" type="parent" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">

        <xsd:unique name="UniqueChildId">
          <xsd:selector xpath=".//*[not(child::childgroup)]"></xsd:selector>
          <xsd:field xpath="@id"></xsd:field>
        </xsd:unique>

      </xsd:element>
```

Third Try

```html
     <xsd:element name="parent" type="parent" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">

        <xsd:unique name="UniqueChildId">
          <xsd:selector xpath="child::*[not(childgroup)]"></xsd:selector>
          <xsd:field xpath="@id"></xsd:field>
        </xsd:unique>

      </xsd:element>
```

Thanks for your help!

#### Invalid Xml

E.g.1

```html
  <parentgroup>

    <parent id="1">
      <child id="2" />
      <child id="3" />
      <childgroup id="7">
        <child id="5" />
        <child id="6" />
      </childgroup>
      <child id="7" />
    </parent>


    <parent id="8">
      <childgroup id=9">
        <child id="10" />
        <child id="9" />
      </childgroup>
      <child id="12" />
      <child id="13" />
      <childgroup id="14">
        <child id="15" />
        <child id="16" />
      </childgroup>
    </parent>

  </parentgroup>
```

Reason

1. Invalid because in first parent: childgroup id="7" has same id as child id="7"
2. Invalid because in second parent: child id="9" has same id as his "father" childgroup id="9"

E.g.2

```html
  <parentgroup>

    <parent id="1">
      <child id="2" />
      <child id="3" />
      <childgroup id="4">
        <child id="5" />
        <child id="7" />
      </childgroup>
      <child id="7" />
    </parent>


    <parent id="8">
      <childgroup id=9">
        <child id="10" />
        <child id="8" />
      </childgroup>
      <child id="12" />
      <child id="14" />
      <childgroup id="14">
        <child id="15" />
        <child id="16" />
      </childgroup>
    </parent>

  </parentgroup>
```

Reason

1. Invalid because in second parent: childgroup id="14" has same id as child id="14"

E.g.2

```html
  <parentgroup>

    <parent id="1">
      <child id="2" />
      <child id="7" />
      <childgroup id="4">
        <child id="5" />
        <child id="6" />
      </childgroup>
      <child id="7" />
    </parent>


    <parent id="8">
      <childgroup id=9">
        <child id="10" />
        <child id="11" />
      </childgroup>
      <child id="12" />
      <child id="14" />
      <childgroup id="15">
        <child id="16" />
        <child id="11" />
      </childgroup>
    </parent>

  </parentgroup>
```

Reason

1. Invalid because in first parent: child id="7" has same id as child id="7"

E.g.2

```html
  <parentgroup>

    <parent id="1">
      <child id="2" />
      <child id="3" />
      <childgroup id="4">
        <child id="1" />
        <child id="2" />
      </childgroup>
      <child id="7" />
    </parent>


    <parent id="8">
      <childgroup id=9">
        <child id="10" />
        <child id="11" />
      </childgroup>
      <child id="12" />
      <child id="14" />
      <childgroup id="9">
        <child id="16" />
        <child id="11" />
      </childgroup>
    </parent>

  </parentgroup>
```

Reason

1. Invalid because in second parent: childgroup id="9" has same id as childgroup id="9"

#### Valid Xml

E.g.1

```html
  <parentgroup>

    <parent id="1">
      <child id="2" />
      <child id="3" />
      <childgroup id="4">
        <child id="5" />
        <child id="6" />
      </childgroup>
      <child id="7" />
    </parent>


    <parent id="8">
      <childgroup id=1">
        <child id="2" />
        <child id="3" />
      </childgroup>
      <child id="4" />
      <child id="5" />
      <childgroup id="6">
        <child id="7" />
        <child id="9" />
      </childgroup>
    </parent>

  </parentgroup>
```

E.g.2

```html
  <parentgroup>

    <parent id="1">
      <child id="2" />
      <child id="3" />
      <childgroup id="4">
        <child id="5" />
        <child id="7" />
      </childgroup>
      <child id="7" />
    </parent>


    <parent id="8">
      <childgroup id=1">
        <child id="2" />
        <child id="5" />
      </childgroup>
      <child id="4" />
      <child id="5" />
      <childgroup id="6">
        <child id="2" />
        <child id="5" />
      </childgroup>
    </parent>

  </parentgroup>
```

Comment: I saw you tried to edit my response, as a way to refine your question. From what I could gather from your edit, you wanted something different in ways that your initial sample XML/XSD and narrative did not capture. What you have to keep in mind is that for what you've literally asked, the answer is correct. It is up to you to decide whether to update the question, create a new question which captures your different/generic scenario, and/or remove this question all together; you need to appreciate that the answer definitely helped you understand at least how to phrase a better question.

Comment: no sorry thats not correct, I did not want to edit your answer, I just wanted to give an answer, I dont now how this could happen, sorry for that.

Comment: no sorry thats not correct, I did not want to edit your answer, I just wanted to give an answer, I dont now how this could happen, sorry for that, but you can guess I am a novice. Back to my question, I was asking how to exclude one special descendant node of a xpath descendant-self selection, I tried to explain myself as best as I could, I am sorry if you misunderstood me and thank you for cleaning up my markup and trying to help me but, you just showed me how to simple select some nodes, but I see what you want from me, I will try another board and click on "this answer is useful" for you.

Comment: In re-reading the **Task** section, I still don't understand what is it that doesn't work for you. Could you please update your question with an sample XML that i) is invalid as per the **Task** description, and ii) passes validation with the XSD I've provided?

Comment: @Petru I edit my question now with few examples.

Comment: I've tested all XMLs you published - you could do the same ;) - and they work as per your expectations. Which means I've correctly interpreted your requirements. I suspect the problem is that you didn't try it yourself using some sort of XML editor that supports XSD validation, or you tried to interpret the XPaths but somehow misread them. Thank you for following up with additional samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've cleaned up and corrected your errors. Below is the new XSD that works with the posted XML and the requirements the way I understood them. I hope the diagram below helps you visualize better the constraints and the XPath you should use.

[image: QTAssistant diagram showing XSD constraints]

The modified XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="parentgroup" type="parentgroup">
        <xsd:unique name="UniqueParentId">
            <xsd:selector xpath="parent"/>
            <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xsd:unique>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="parentgroup">
        <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="parent" type="parent" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:unique name="UniqueChildId">
                    <xsd:selector xpath=".|childgroup|child"/>
                    <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
                </xsd:unique>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:int"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="parent">
        <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="child" type="child" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="childgroup" type="childgroup" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:unique name="UniqueChildIdInChildGroup">
                    <xsd:selector xpath=".|child"/>
                    <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
                </xsd:unique>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:choice>
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:int"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="childgroup">
        <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="child" type="child" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:int"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="child">
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:int"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

UPDATE: The XSD works fine with all sample XMLs. Here is what QTAssistant is saying about each:

Invalid:
E.g. 1:

`Error occurred while loading [], line 9 position 4
There is a duplicate key sequence '7' for the 'UniqueChildId' key or unique identity constraint.
Error occurred while loading [], line 15 position 5
There is a duplicate key sequence '9' for the 'UniqueChildIdInChildGroup' key or unique identity constraint.
ParentChildChildGroup-Inv-Eg1.xml is invalid.`

E.g. 2:

`Error occurred while loading [], line 21 position 5
There is a duplicate key sequence '14' for the 'UniqueChildId' key or unique identity constraint.
ParentChildChildGroup-Inv-Eg2.xml is invalid.`

E.g. 2 (3?):

`Error occurred while loading [], line 9 position 4
There is a duplicate key sequence '7' for the 'UniqueChildId' key or unique identity constraint.
ParentChildChildGroup-Inv-Eg3.xml is invalid.`

E.g. 2 (4?):

`Error occurred while loading [], line 21 position 5
There is a duplicate key sequence '9' for the 'UniqueChildId' key or unique identity constraint.
ParentChildChildGroup-Inv-Eg4.xml is invalid.`

What you described as valid XMLs are successfully validated.

Comment: no sorry thats not correct, I did not want to edit your answer, I just wanted to give an answer, I dont now how this could happen, sorry for that, but you can guess I am a novice. Back to my question, I was asking how to exclude one special descendant node of a xpath descendant-self selection, I tried to explain myself as best as I could, I am sorry if you misunderstood me and thank you for cleaning up my markup and trying to help me but, you just showed me how to simple select some nodes, but I see what you want from me, I will try another board and click on "this answer is useful" for you.